# Remove alphabetical order from wordpress categories

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am new to programming and WordPress.

I am working on a project where I am using a custom taxonomy (tag). When I select my tag in the admin panel (post), it automatically gets arranged in alphabetical order.

I'd like to stop that behavior, as I want to display the tags in the order I selected them.

Comment: How are you selecting your order, and how are you saving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: just place this in your functions.php:

```
/**
 * Sort post_tags by term_order
 *
 * @param array $terms array of objects to be replaced with sorted list
 * @param integer $id post id
 * @param string $taxonomy only 'post_tag' is changed.
 * @return array of objects
 */
function plugin_get_the_ordered_terms ( $terms, $id, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'post_tag' != $taxonomy ) // only ordering tags for now but could add other taxonomies here.
        return $terms;

    $terms = wp_cache_get($id, "{$taxonomy}_relationships_sorted");
    if ( false === $terms ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomy, array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
        wp_cache_add($id, $terms, $taxonomy . '_relationships_sorted');
    }

    return $terms;
}

add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'plugin_get_the_ordered_terms' , 10, 4 );

/**
 * Adds sorting by term_order to post_tag by doing a partial register replacing
 * the default
 */
function plugin_register_sorted_post_tag () {
    register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'post', array( 'sort' => true, 'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'plugin_register_sorted_post_tag' );
```

(Credit goes to [lgedeon on the Wordpress Core Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9547#comment:7))

Now all you need to do is enter the tags in the order you want them to appear.

Note: the above code shows how to do this for **post_tag**. If you want a different taxonomy, just update the above code with the taxonomy name you want.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying categories you should use

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array('orderby' => 'ID')); ?>
```

Instead of `ID` you can use `name`,`slug`,`count` or `term_group`. See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories)

Comment: you didn't got me  in admin panel (post) when i select my tag it automatically get arranged in alphabetical order (in admin panel). i want to stop it as i want to display the tags in the order i select.(**tag which i select first should come first the tag i select second should come second**).@Tolea Bivol

Comment: Still dont get it , Some screenshots with some arrows and short explanations on them might clear the question pls